# Using NYTProf with Mason under mod_perl

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl2, mason

I'm trying to profile a web application written on top of HTML::Mason, I managed to set the profiler but it doesn't seem to pick-up the code inside the components. Is there a way to profile Mason applications using NYTProf?

Answer (score 2):

I realize you're deploying this app under mod_perl, but one way to handle this would be to deploy under Plack and then use [Plack::Middleware::Debug::Profiler::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aMiddleware%3a%3aDebug%3a%3aProfiler%3a%3aNYTProf).  I haven't done this for Mason apps, but it was almost trivial to get some CGI::Application code running under Plack.  Once you are able to deploy under Plack you get access to lots of great middleware components for debugging.  If you can do this with little or no changes to the app itself, you could still continue to deploy to production under mod_perl but use Plack in development for stuff like NYTProf.

EDIT: I see now that I should have pointed you at [Devel::NYTProf::Apache](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel%3a%3aNYTProf%3a%3aApache).

Comment: I think I can get the application to run under Plack, thanks for the tip I will try it and let you know if this solution worked.

Comment: never got Devel::NYTProf::Apache to work satisfactorily here.  plack is a much better option.